# Wunderlist’s API with Guzzle - Create Task - Bad Request 400

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, wunderlist

I'm trying out the Wunderlist API and have been following this [helpful tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/crash-course-of-wunderlists-api-with-guzzle/). They also provide a [demo on Github](https://github.com/upchuk/wunderlist-api-demo). It works fine with the GET calls (and PATCH), but when I try to create a new task with a POST request, it returns bad request, client error: 400.

WunderlistClient.php

```
public function createTask($name, $list_id, $task = []) {
    if (!is_numeric($list_id)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The list id must be numeric.');
    }
    $task['name'] = $name;
    $task['list_id'] = $list_id;
    $response = $this->client->post('tasks', ['body' => json_encode($task)]);
    $this->checkResponseStatusCode($response, 201);
    return json_decode($response->getBody());
}
```

index.php

```
try {
    $created = $wunderlist->createTask('New Task', $list_id);
    dump($created);
}
catch(\Exception $exception) {
    dump($exception);
}
```

I added a createList function, which only requires title, and that did work.

```
public function createList($title, $list = []) {
    $list['title'] = $title;
    $response = $this->client->post('lists', ['body' => json_encode($list)]);
    $this->checkResponseStatusCode($response, 201);
    return json_decode($response->getBody());
}
```

Why am I unable to create [tasks](https://developer.wunderlist.com/documentation/endpoints/task)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to switch 'name' to 'title'.

```
public function createTask($title, $list_id, $task = []) {
    if (!is_numeric($list_id)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The list id must be numeric.');
    }
    $task['title'] = $title;
    $task['list_id'] = $list_id;
    $response = $this->client->post('tasks', ['body' => json_encode($task)]);
    $this->checkResponseStatusCode($response, 201);
    return json_decode($response->getBody());
}
```